# Why function not fired when I make seletion?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I work on my mvc 5 project.
I have `ul li` element. When I make selection from ul element I want to fire jquery function and implement postback call.

I have this HTML code:

```
        <ul class="top-links list-inline">
            <li>
                <a class="dropdown-toggle no-text-underline" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><img class="flag-lang" src="/assets/images/flags/il.png" width="16" height="11" alt="lang" /> HEBROW</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-langs dropdown-menu" doselection>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"><img class="flag-lang" src="~/assets/images/flags/il.png" width="16" height="11" alt="lang" /> HEBROW</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"><img class="flag-lang" src="/assets/images/flags/us.png" width="16" height="11" alt="lang" /> ENGLISH</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"><img class="flag-lang" src="/assets/images/flags/de.png" width="16" height="11" alt="lang" /> GERMAN</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"><img class="flag-lang" src="/assets/images/flags/ru.png" width="16" height="11" alt="lang" /> RUSSIAN</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

And here is event handler:

```
    (function ($) {
       $("ul li").click(function () {
           $(this).parents("form").submit(); // post form
        });     
    })(jQuery);
```

But when I make selection in ul element function above not fired.

**UPDATE:**

I tryed this(I removed postback call):

```
    (function ($) {
        $("ul li").click(function () {
            alert("test!!!");
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

Still the function is not fired.

Any idea  what do I miss?

Comment: if you place an alert message instead of submiting the post does it work?

Comment: @Kostis please see update.

Comment: Take a look here...the event fires successfully but for the sublist it fires 2 times. https://jsfiddle.net/e3dqqwmq/

Comment: @Kostis: That's because it's bubbling up to the higher level `ul`

Comment: @Kostis it was silly mistake I tried to fire JQuery function before JQuery  library  loaded.